# Random name picker for a contest

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

I have an array of 4 names, and was wondering what the best best way to reliably pick 1 name for a contest would be. I've read online that javascripts `Math.Random` is only `pseudo random`. Which makes me wonder, would this be a fair enough function to put a prize on the line?

The picking process won't be externally/customer facing, so I'm not worried about how it looks, more just about how fair it would be.

```
$(".randomize").click(function() {
  var contestents = [{
    person: "Kareem"
  }, {
    person: "Charlie"
  }, {
    person: "Hobie"
  }, {
    person: "Hoder"
  }];

  var winner = Math.floor(Math.random() * contestents.length)
  $('div').html(contestents[winner].person);
});
```

**[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/mpao4f5d/1/)**

If not, how could I randomize this even more to be fair enough to put a prize on the line.

Comment: Yes, Math.random should be fine for this

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. `Math.random` is indeed pseudo-random. However, its algorithm is actually quite good. In [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062902/how-random-is-javascripts-math-random), a concern is brought up that the randomly generated numbers tend to all have the same number of digits. While this was statistically proven to make sense, you won't run into a similar problem since you are only dealing with single digit numbers.

`Math.random` should be random enough for your purposes. However, if you want to get truly random numbers to be absolutely fair, check out [RANDOM.ORG](https://www.random.org/). This, however, would obviously be a lot more unwieldy than just using Math.random.